# Using proxy on read-only object property of class

Tags: javascript

I'm having a class that extends class from 3rd party library, in parent class I have `props` property that in it's turn has `disabled` property inside.

I want to track from where `props.disabled` is set. The most natural solution for that is doing the following in my class

```
this.props = new Proxy(
    this.props,
    {
        set(target, prop, val) {
            if (prop === 'disabled') {
                debugger;
            }
        }
    }
)
```

But I cant do that because `props` is read-only and I cant change that, cause it's defined in parent class in 3rd party library.

How can I track from where `props.disabled` is set?

Comment: Instead of extending the class, you could maybe create a wrapper class, one issue here is that of `instanceOf`,  but you could use `Symbol.hasInstance` on the base class to include yours.

Comment: @Keith the bad thing here is that I'm debugging existing code, bot developing new, so it's impossible to use wrapper class instead of `extends`